# Paypal C# REST API redirect urls not working on Payment object

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, paypal, redirect

I started using the Paypal .Net SDK to manage basic transactions on our .Net MVC application.

I created my first payment following [this example](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Quick-Start) but the Payment object has null redirect_urls. Code below shows how I assign those urls:

```
var payment = Payment.Create(apiContext, new Payment
{
    redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls
    {
        return_url = "https://localhost:44300/Payments/CheckoutReview",
        cancel_url = "https://localhost:44300/Payments/CheckoutCancel"
    },
    intent = "sale",
    payer = new Payer
etcetera...
```

Debugging the code I could see `payment.redirect_urls=null`
[image]

I use the chance to ask on how should I handle the response once those urls are set correctly. I have two controller functions for that purpose. According to the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment), the returned value from issuing a payment is a Payment object with a `links` attribute to redirect the customer to the payment platform. Those are my response controllers:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public void CheckoutReview(Payment response)
{
    Redirect(response.links[1].href);
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public void CheckoutCancel(Payment response)
{
    ViewBag.alert("Transaction cancelled");
    RedirectToAction("BuyCredti");
}
```

Do I need to `AllowAnonymous`? Will it be a POST `[HttpPost]`?

Thanks!

Comment: This is Jason, the developer for the PayPal .NET SDK. The null `redirect_urls` is a result of the PayPal REST API not responding with that information in the resource object.  Even doing a `Get()` for the resource yields the same result.  This unfortunately appears to be a bug with the API.  I'll notify the API team of the issue.  Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: will you notify me when there is a solution?

Comment: Yes; however, I don't have an ETA on when this issue will be resolved.